# Is White in a weaker position?

Tags: analysis, strategy, learning

Is White in a weaker position than Black? How do I analyze this position?

```
[FEN "2rq2kr/p1ppbp2/1pn1p1pP/4P3/3P2Qn/2PB4/PP3P2/RNB1K2R w - - 0 1"]
```

From this point onward, I tried a mobile chess-free app and turned the board, on each move. I mean from both ends that the computer was playing. But each time White lost or drew at max. How can I say at this stage that White is in a weaker position? What are the key points?

Comment: White is definitely not in a worse position

Comment: I suppose it is Black's move, since otherwise he is quickly lost ? Anyway, please precise whose move it is in the body of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[fen "2rq2kr/p1ppbp2/1pn1p1pP/4P3/3P2Qn/2P5/PP3P2/RNB1K2R w - - 0 1"]
```

> Is white in a weaker position then black? ... What are the key points?

The key points are -

1. White is a whole piece down for no compensation
2. White has no attack
3. White has no pawn levers
4. The white h pawn is weak and black can round it up at leisure and take it

In short, white is not just weaker than black, white is completely lost

> Please review it again. My bad, I missed the white bishop, now edited
> in Fen

Well, a white bishop suddenly appearing on d3 changes everything. The g6 pawn is now a major problem for black. With white to move (as indicated by your fen) black is just lost. The knight on h4 is en prise. White can just take it. Here's what happens if black tries to recapture.

```
[fen "2rq2kr/p1ppbp2/1pn1p1pP/4P3/3P2Qn/2PB4/PP3P2/RNB1K2R w - - 0 1"]

1. Rxh4 Bxh4 2. Bxg6 fxg6 (2...Kf8 3. Bxf7 Kxf7 4. Qg7+ Ke8 5. Qxh8+ Ke7 6. Qg7+ Ke8 7. h7) 3. Qxg6+ Kf8 4. Qg7+ Ke8 5. Qxh8+ Ke7 6. Qg7+ Ke8 7. h7
```

Comment: Please review it again. My bad, I missed the white bishop, now edited in Fen.

Answer (score 2):

White has an attack going with Rxh4 followed by Bxg6.

Black has no attack/no plan. One now needs to calculate if Rxh4 and Bxg6 is forcing enough for white.

With a quick calculation one can see that White's pieces flow and hence White is in fact winning here.

Answer (score 0):

Who is on  the move?

With white to move it looks like white is better off although black has positional advantage in the long run unless white has tactics to finish things.

This is hard to tell and no wonder your computers have problems!